# Failed to program network rules for vm after upgrading to Cloudstack 4.13

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I upgraded my Cloudstack from 4.9 to 4.13. After that, I have an issue with the VM Network that does not work. So now, I can not access to all of VM via SSH, but I can access to them via Console on Cloudstack Web Management.
This is the error log when I start a VM:

> INFO  [kvm.storage.LibvirtStorageAdaptor] (agentRequest-Handler-3:) (logid:002d8f0d) Trying to fetch storage pool f17b1753-6ed4-33ae-9f28-eef726a9380d from libvirt
>   WARN  [resource.wrapper.LibvirtSecurityGroupRulesCommandWrapper] (agentRequest-Handler-4:) (logid:d4c83a3d) Failed to program network rules for vm i-2-354-VM
>   ==> /var/log/cloudstack/agent/agent.log <==
>   2019-12-07 22:00:19,049 WARN  [resource.wrapper.LibvirtSecurityGroupRulesCommandWrapper] (agentRequest-Handler-5:null) (logid:1a86a19a) Failed to program network rules for vm i-2-354-VM
>
> ==> /var/log/cloudstack/agent/cloudstack-agent.out <==
>   DEBUG [cloud.agent.Agent] (agentRequest-Handler-5:) (logid:1a86a19a) Seq 12-6579477580611584015:  { Ans: , MgmtId: 275796944525698, via: 12, Ver: v1, Flags: 110, [{"com.cloud.agent.api.SecurityGroupRuleAnswer":{"logSequenceNumber":10,"vmId":354,"reason":"PROGRAMMING_FAILED","result":false,"details":"programming network rules failed","wait":0}}] }
>
> ==> /var/log/cloudstack/agent/agent.log <==
>   2019-12-07 22:00:19,050 DEBUG [cloud.agent.Agent] (agentRequest-Handler-5:null) (logid:1a86a19a) Seq 12-6579477580611584015:  { Ans: , MgmtId: 275796944525698, via: 12, Ver: v1, Flags: 110, [{"com.cloud.agent.api.SecurityGroupRuleAnswer":{"logSequenceNumber":10,"vmId":354,"reason":"PROGRAMMING_FAILED","result":false,"details":"programming network rules failed","wait":0}}] }

I have no idea for that (tried restart cloudstack-agent, virtual router, ).
Please help me
Thank you